# Import code the Net Framework to Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll

I'm started create a program to make a label on gif. At the moment, worked on Console App (.Net Framework) but when send the final solution to Console App, my IDE return errors.

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

pfc.AddFontFile(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf"));
string originalImgPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\1.gif";


System.Drawing.Image IMG = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(originalImgPath);
FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(IMG.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
int frameCount = IMG.GetFrameCount(dimension);
GifBitmapEncoder gEnc = new GifBitmapEncoder(); // The type or namespace name 'GifBitmapEncoder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  **Error Message 1**
for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
{
    // Get each frame
    IMG.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);
    var aFrame = new Bitmap(IMG);

    // Draw a white rectangle

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(aFrame);
    int cornerRadius = 10;
    int rectangleX = aFrame.Width / 10;
    int rectangleY = aFrame.Height - 60;
    int rectangleWidth = Convert.ToInt32(aFrame.Width / 1.21);
    int rectangleHeight = aFrame.Height / 4;

    // Create a GraphicsPath with rounded rectangle shape
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddArc(rectangleX, rectangleY, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90); // Top-left corner
    path.AddArc(rectangleX + rectangleWidth - cornerRadius, rectangleY, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90); // Top-right corner
    path.AddArc(rectangleX + rectangleWidth - cornerRadius, rectangleY + rectangleHeight - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90); // Bottom-right corner
    path.AddArc(rectangleX, rectangleY + rectangleHeight - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90); // Bottom-left corner
    path.CloseFigure();

    // Fill the rounded rectangle with white color
    graphics.FillPath(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, path);
    // Write the text on the rectangle

    string nome = "text";
    System.Drawing.FontFamily fontFamily = pfc.Families[0];
    int fontSize = 13;
    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(nome, font);
    graphics.DrawString($"\tWelcome!!", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt32(aFrame.Width / 3.7), aFrame.Height - 50);
    graphics.DrawString($"\n{nome}!!", new System.Drawing.Font(pfc.Families[0], 13, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, (rectangleX + (rectangleWidth - (int)textSize.Width) / 2), aFrame.Height - 50);

    var src = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                aFrame.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()); // add reference to WindwosBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral **Error Message 2**

    // Merge frames
    gEnc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(src)); // The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
}

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    gEnc.Save(ms);
    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    var newBytes = new List<byte>();
    newBytes.AddRange(fileBytes.Take(13));
    newBytes.AddRange(new byte[] { 33, 255, 11, 78, 69, 84, 83, 67, 65, 80, 69, 50, 46, 48, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0 });
    newBytes.AddRange(fileBytes.Skip(13));
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"..\tenor-1.gif", newBytes.ToArray());
}
```

[image: Error Message 1, with import System.Windows.Media.Imaging]
[image: Error Message 2, Int32Rect]

The object is solve the problem, because i need make that code work on Console App to run on docker.

Comment: We don't post images of error messages here. Paste the text. Even experienced developers often have to google these things to refresh their memory, and if they have to retype from the image many will just move on to another question, meaning you're much less likely to get a good answer.

Comment: But also, have you read the messages? Specifically, the part that tells you exactly how to fix this (add a reference to the WindowsBase library)?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn In .NET Core, you don't add references to WindowsBase, you set `UseWPF` to true in your .csproj.

Comment: OP should actually switch to a solution that does not require UI libraries. As far as I understand this, a pure image manipulation library would be preferable. Possibly an OS agnostic one, so this can be used in Windows as well as Linux based containers.

Comment: See also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change these lines in `.csproj` file of your console app:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to these (you have to add postfix `-windows` target framework name):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I dunno version of *.NET*, used in your project though, so change `5.0` to your version.

Apart from that if you plan to running it on non-Windows *Docker* container, you will have problem then. In this case you should think about reimplement your app, using different libraries or use Windows-based *Docker* container.