# Create a image docker on net7.0-windows

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

Recently I asked a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746165/import-code-the-net-framework-to-net-core/76746225#76746225) about adding System.Drawing.Common on console app. But when I build an image on Visual Studio Code it returns this...

[image]

I would like run the project on docker.
I change the file *.csproj like Bart tell me:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>    
    <UseWPF>True</UseWPF>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting> <!-- Add this line -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus" Version="5.0.0-nightly-01492" />
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus.CommandsNext" Version="5.0.0-nightly-01492" />
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus.Interactivity" Version="5.0.0-nightly-01492" />
    <PackageReference Include="DSharpPlus.SlashCommands" Version="5.0.0-nightly-01492" />
    <PackageReference Include="LibGit2Sharp" Version="0.26.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="109.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TwitchLib.Api" Version="3.9.0-preview-f7f2908" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I made the change on *.csproj I didn't change the file Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
 
# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser
 
 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerConsole.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerConsole.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DockerConsole.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
 
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerConsole.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
 
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerConsole.dll"]
```

Do I need to change something on Dockerfile?

Comment: We prefer to have the text of errors copied and pasted as text rather than screenshots in image format.  It makes the question more searchable and accessible as well as [many other reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: In short, you cannot create a Linux based image but a Windows Server based one.

Comment: @LexLi ehn ... i cannot download dll and run the program??

Comment: The Windows specific profiles are not supported on non-Windows OSes. I assume that’s common knowledge.